# Pattern match function against empty map

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm playing around with pattern match and I found out, that it's not quite easy to pattern match parameters of a method against an empty map. I thought it would go something like this:

```elixir
defmodule PatternMatch do
  def modify(%{}) do
    %{}
  end

  def modify(map) do
    # expensive operation
    %{ modified: "map" }
  end
end
```

But it seems like the first function clause matches arbitrary maps:

```bash
iex> PatternMatch.modify(%{a: "map"})
==> %{}
```

Is there another way to check for empty maps?

Comment: Would the order of the function clauses play into this issue too?  I mean would an empty map always match and therefore need to be the last function clause?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It works this way by design, but admittedly it can be a bit confusing at first glance. This feature allows you to destructure maps using pattern matching, without having to specify all keys. For example:

```bash
iex> %{b: value} = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    
iex> value
2
```

Consequently, `%{}` will match any map. If you want to match an empty map in a function, you have to use a guard clause:

```elixir
defmodule PatternMatch do
  def modify(map) when map == %{} do
    %{}
  end

  def modify(map) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I pattern-matched on `%{}` to tell my code that is was not necessary to try to store an empty map in the database... that's what is called a bug. It surprised me because I forgot what I read before in the books. That meant no data in the DB for 10 days. Lucky me, it was a dev setup

Comment: Is `%{}` still supposed to match any map still? It appears that `%{a: 1} != %{}` now.

Comment: @brettinternet did you maybe try `%{a: 1} = %{}` to come to this conclusion? (It gives a NoMatchError). The expression `a = b` is not equivalent to `b = a` in Elixir. The left part is a pattern, while the right part is a value.

Comment: For `==` and `!=` it's a different story, this is not pattern matching but equality operators which always behaved the way you described. That's exactly the reason why we need to use `==` in a guard instead of just matching `%{}` in the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was wondering about

Answer (score 44):

In addition to @PatrickOscity's answer (which I would use for an empty map), you can use a [map_size/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#map_size/1) guard to match against maps with a number of keys:

```elixir
defmodule PatternMatch do
  def modify(map) when map_size(map) == 0 do
    %{}
  end

  def modify(map) when map_size(map) == 1 do
    #something else
  end

  def modify(map) do
    # expensive operation
    %{ modified: "map" }
  end
end
```

Here is an output from iex using `Kernel.match?/2` to show `map_size/1` in action:

```bash
iex(6)> Kernel.match?(map when map_size(map) == 1, %{})
false

iex(7)> Kernel.match?(map when map_size(map) == 1, %{foo: "bar"})
true
```

Comment: Nice addition. Small correction: I think it should be `when map_size(map) ...` instead of `when map_size ...`

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to all the cool answers provided so far, you may also consider the usage of the [unary pin operator](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator) that looks like a hat or an upper arrow point. You use it to prefix a variable with it to ensure you pattern match against its value, as stated in the relevant documentation:

> Use the pin operator ^ when you want to pattern match against an
>   existing variable’s value rather than rebinding the variable

Following is an example:

```
defmodule A do
  def determine_map_volume(some_map) do
    an_empty_map = %{}

    some_map
    |> case do
    ^an_empty_map -> :empty  # Application of pin operator
    _ -> :not_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Which you can verify as follows:

```
A.determine_map_volume(%{})
:empty
A.determine_map_volume(%{a: 1})
:not_empty
```

Which method you intend to use depends on your personal/organizational preference for the readability of your code.