# Pattern match an empty MapSet

Tags: elixir

Given a MapSet, how can one detect if it's empty using pattern matching?

```
# What goes in the question marks?
def my_func(????), do: IO.puts("This mapset is empty")
def my_func(%MapSet{}), do: IO.puts("This mapset is not empty")

my_func(MapSet.new())
```

If this were a list, I would have just matched it on `([])` but that doesn't work for MapSets (because the type is different)

Here are some of the other things I've tried, unsuccessfully.

```
def myfunc([]), do: IO.puts("This only works for lists")
# This is a syntax error
# def myfunc(MapSize.new())

def myfunc(%MapSet{}), do: IO.puts("This matches every mapset")
def myfunc(a) when map_size(a), do: IO.puts("the map size is always 3")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also consider [the solution I provided for matching against an empty map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248816/pattern-match-function-against-empty-map) as follows:

```
defmodule A do
  def empty?(some_map_set = %MapSet{}) do
    an_empty_map_set = MapSet.new

    some_map_set
    |> case do
    ^an_empty_map_set ->true  # Application of pin operator
    _ -> false
    end
  end
end
```

You can test as follows:

`A.empty?(MapSet.new)`

and

`A.empty?(MapSet.new([1]))`

In that link you can see other solutions that you can leverage accordingly.
One is already provided by @dogbert. 
The other solution would work as follows:

```
defmodule A do
  @empty MapSet.new
  def empty?(some_map_set) when some_map_set == @empty, do: true
  def empty?(%MapSet{}), do: false
end
```

Comment: There is MapSet.size, but I doubt that is guard safe.

Comment: The @empty is a nice way of doing it, I went with this way. It doesn't rely on internal properties of the mapset

Answer (score 7):

A MapSet stores its entries in a field called `map`. I'm not 100% sure whether this is an implementation detail or is it guaranteed to remain the same, but for now you can check whether the `map` field is empty using `map_size/1`:

```
defmodule A do
  def empty?(%MapSet{map: map}) when map_size(map) == 0, do: true
  def empty?(%MapSet{}), do: false
end

IO.inspect A.empty?(MapSet.new)
IO.inspect A.empty?(MapSet.new([1, 2]))
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Based on [the MapSet docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html), this appears to not be supported: "Note that . . . the struct fields are private and must not be accessed directly." (With that said, though, I'm totally doing it this way and if they ever change the MapSet implementation in a way that breaks it, I'll catch it in test.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a hacky but still legit way to achieve a goal:

```rb
defmodule MapSetTest do
  def my_func(map_set, empty_map_set \\ MapSet.new)
  def my_func(empty_map_set, empty_map_set),
    do: IO.puts("This mapset is empty")
  def my_func(%MapSet{}, _),
    do: IO.puts("This mapset is not empty")
end

MapSetTest.my_func(MapSet.new)      #⇒ This mapset is empty
MapSetTest.my_func(MapSet.new([]))  #⇒ This mapset is empty
MapSetTest.my_func(MapSet.new([1])) #⇒ This mapset is not empty
```

The trick here is that while we cannot call `MapSet.new` directly in match, we can assign it’s value to be the default for the hidden second argument.

Answer (score -1):

This approach does not use pattern matching, but if your goal to tell whether a `MapSet` is empty, you can use [`Enum.empty?()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.14.5/Enum.html#empty?/1).

```
iex(1)> [] |> MapSet.new() |> Enum.empty?()
true
```

```
iex(2)> [1] |> MapSet.new() |> Enum.empty?()
false
```